# Appropriate expression (vulgar or not) to express serious shock/surprise/suddenly-perceived danger?

Tags: idioms

**I'm seeking contextually-appropriate expressions for shocked surprise, even better would be seriously shocked/scared surprise.  Vulgar is fine,**

For context, this query is for dialog for a character in a novel.) A literal translation of, "Oh, shit!" is doable, but I doubt that colloquial or simply not what an Italian speaker would say.

I'm looking to express *serious* surprise.  Not simply the, "You're being audited by the tax authorities" level of badness.  **Instead, I'm seeking something to express the "doctors say it's cancerous, but aren't sure if it's operable" level of bad, bad news received.**  An old-school expression would be especially good. (The character learned the language in southern Italy circa WWII; now speaks English -- except when *badly* rattled.)  Any suggestions for phrases to use + in-context translation would be greatly appreciated.  Any online resources (for swear words, curses, vulgar phrases)  similarly appreciated.

Comment: I think *diavolo!*, *al diavolo* o *all'inferno* are not satisfying, are they?

Comment: Not a reference, but here you can find some hint: https://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/porca-eva.1911687/&ved=0ahUKEwi2vsmmwMXTAhVGrRQKHcULBVk4ChAWCC8wCA&usg=AFQjCNGOPbNvLwsLKO7XCYfoyDQmSGldDA&sig2=scvJI8vFGYspsnpY8yNF-A

Comment: @N74  I don't read/speak Italian.  Would you kindly tell me how that would translate?  (I'm guessing Devil and Hell basically, but the prepositions elude me, as does the non-literal import.)

Comment: Well, *all'inferno* sounds like *go to Hell* and *al diavolo* has the same meaning (go to Devil). With *diavolo!* you are just swearing at the Devil. To be more vulgar you can use the many forms of *porco/porco ...*.

Comment: @N74: For me *al diavolo* sounds more like someone gets annoyed at something and decides to give it up.

Comment: what about "porcatroia!" ?

Comment: Being from southern Italy, you could use dialectal expression. But in this way you have to be more specific about the location. If your character is from Campania, Abruzzo or Molise you may use "_Mannaggia sant Nient_" which means "_For the sake of Saint Nothing_"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **[Merda!](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/merda#Italian)**

is the translation of "*Shit!*", and is fine.

If you want something stronger, you can insult something. For example:

> **[Porca troia!](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/porca_troia)**

is insulting a (nonexisting) whore.

Italians also swear at God and call him names when something really bad happens, but I'm not teaching you that since it's considered very offensive, is a big sin for the majority religion and [it is illegal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blasphemy_law#Italy) (yes, we are allowed to offend sex workers but not some imaginary entity)

Comment: +1 for the last parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "oh mio dio, non è possibile" as a shock expression, which means "oh my God, it can't be possible"